# Counting k-tuples constrained to contain all elements

Tags: combinatorics

The elements for the k-tuples are: $\{1,2,\ ...\ ,n\}$. I know the total amount of tuples is $n^k$, but I fail to find a simple way to count the part of them containing all elements.

In mathematica I made this function, which does the thing (to be able to verify):

```
count[n_, k_] := Sum[Fold[{#[[1]] - #2, #[[2]] Binomial[#[[1]], #2]} &,
{n, 1}, Tally[i][[All, 2]]][[2]]/Times @@ (i!) k!, {i, IntegerPartitions[k, {n}]}]
```

It's not inefficient, however it's no way near the simple stuff my teacher wants. Does a simple formula even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are looking for the number of surjective (onto) functions from a set of size $k$ to a set of size $n$--in your case, the set of size $n$ is $\{1, 2,...,n\}$.

This can be determined with the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

For a function (or equivalently a $k$-tuple) define events: $A_1$: 1 is not used in the $k$-tuple; $A_2$: 2 is not used in the tuple, etc.

Then $A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots \cup A_n$ is the event that at least one number is not used in the tuple.  The size of this set can be counted by inclusion/exclusion.  Then you want the size of the complementary set (since you want every number to be used in the tuple.  But as you noted, you already know the size of the parent set, namely $n^k$.